# Number of ways to take k steps on a path of length N

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

We have a path of length N. At a time we can only take a unit step. How many ways we can take K steps while remaining inside the path. Initially we are at the 0th position.
example N =5

```
 |---|---|---|---|---|

 0   1   2   3   4   5
```

if k = 3 then we move like -

```
0->1->2->1
0->1->0->1
0->1->2->3
```

Can you please give some directions/links on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely to be solvable using combinatorial methods rather than computational methods. But since you're asking on stackoverflow, I assume you want a computational solution.

There's a recurrence relation defining the number of paths ending at `i`:

```
P[N, 0, i] = 1 if i==0 otherwise 0
P[N, K, i] = 0 if i<0 or i>N
P[N, K, i] = P[N, K-1, i-1] + P[N, K-1, i+1]
```

We can iteratively compute the array of `P[N, K, i]` for `i=0..N` for a given `K` from the array `P[N, K-1, i]` for `i=0..N`.

Here's some Python code that does this. It uses a small trick of having an extra `0` at the end of the array so that `r[-1]` and `r[N+1]` are both zero.

```
def paths(N, K):
    r = [1] + [0] * (N+1)
    for _ in xrange(K):
        r = [r[i-1]+r[i+1] for i in xrange(N+1)] + [0]
    return sum(r)

print paths(5, 3)
```

This runs in O(NK) time.

A different (but related) solution is to let `M` be the (N+1) by (N+1) matrix consisting of 1's at positions (i+1,i) and (i,i+1) for i=0..N+1, and 0's elsewhere -- that is, 1's on the subdiagonal and superdiagonal. Then `M^K` (that is, `M` raised to the `K`th power) contains at position (i, j) the number of paths from `i` to `j` in `K` steps. So `sum(M^K[0,i] for i=0..N)` is the total number of all paths starting at 0 of length `K`. This runs in O(N^3logK) time, so is better than the iterative method only if `K` is much larger than `N`.

Comment: Can you please update this answer with the combinatorial approach or give some reference links for that. I not able to understand (never could in past) how both approaches differs.

Comment: could you please post the output of `print paths(5, 3)` for better understanding

Comment: The output is `3`

Answer (score 0):

Java implementation of first approach in accepted answer -

```
for (int i = 0; i <= K; i++) {
  for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++) {
    if (i > 0)
      dp1[i][j] = (dp1[i - 1][j - 1] + dp1[i - 1][j + 1]) % 1000000007;
    else
      dp1[i][j] = 1;
  }
}
System.out.println(dp1[K][N-1])
```

Complexity O(KN)

Java DP implementation, it computes answers for all starting positions and values 1-N and 1-K -

```
for (int i = 0; i <= K; i++) {
  for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++) {
    for (int k = 1; k <= j; k++) {
      if (i > 0)
        dp[k][j][i] =
            (dp[k - 1][j][i - 1] + dp[k + 1][j][i - 1]) % 1000000007;
      else
        dp[k][j][i] = 1;
    }
  }
}
System.out.println(dp[1][5][3]);
```

O(KN^2)

Comment: complexity seems to be too high